# Using EventKit to open Calendar.app at a specific date

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, eventkit

In macOS/Cocoa, is there a way to use EventKit to open the Calendar.app at a specific date/time?

I use `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchAppWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.iCal",
options: .Default, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifier: nil)` to open the app, which works.

In an unsandboxed environment I could use a Scripting Bridge object and do:

```
let calendarApp = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iCal") as! CalendarApplication
if let date = todoItem.properties["icalEventStart"] {
    calendarApp.viewCalendarAt!(date as! NSDate)
}
```

But with sandboxing on, I cannot find a way. EventKit has this user-permission layer, so I thought it a likely candidate to use instead of SB.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with an AppleScript like

```
tell application "Calendar"
    view calendar at current date
end tell
```

There are ways how you could run an AppleScript in a sandboxed app.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Isn't that what Scripting Bridge is doing under the hood?

Comment: Yes, but Scripting Bridge is not usable with Sandboxing as far as I know.